# Explicit computation Legendre transform random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be uniformly distributed in $\{-1,1\}$. Show that the Legendre transform is 
$$
\psi^*(x) = \frac{(1+x)\log(1+x)+(1-x)\log(1-x)}{2}
$$

I computed the moment generated function 
$$
\psi(x) = \frac{(e^{-t}+e^t)}{2}
$$
and tried to apply the definition

$$
\psi^*(x) = \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} tx-\log \psi(t)
$$
but can't get the required form.

Comment: I cannot recognize a moment generating function in your $\psi(x)$ since substitution $t=0$ gives $0$ and should give $1$. I think it should be $\frac12e^t+\frac12e^{-t}$.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

[Using the linked section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation#Understanding_the_transform_in_terms_of_derivatives), we see that $\dfrac{d}{dx} \log(\psi(x)) = \tanh(x)$ is invertible.

Hence, $\dfrac{d}{dx} \phi^*(x) = \tanh^{-1}(x)$.

This is an easy exercise in integration by parts.

Indeed, it is easy to see the solution from the well-known identity $\tanh^{-1}(x) \equiv \dfrac{\log(1+x) - \log(1-x)}{2}$.